# Background image external link URL is not working with ng-style

Tags: angularjs

I'm having some issues with `ng-style`. Here's the code I have at the moment

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/'+ event.image2)'}"
```

The above isn't working, (I have had to remove the bucket name for reasons), but the code works if I have it like this:

```
ng-style="{'background': 'orange'}"
```

This is displaying fine. Why is the URL method not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this instead on the element:

```
<div style="background-image: url('http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/{{event.image2}}')"></div>
```

Comment: you sure the $sce will not trigger this way ? This is what is causing the initial issue.

Comment: @PierreGayvallet Yup, that will work. `$sce` will be used if you have to render the HTML content.

Comment: na, sce triggers on attributes interpolation too. Try an ng-src or event a plain src="http://remote.com/myforged/{urlParam}" attribute

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess event is a variable in your scope, in that case it's just a small typo:

```
ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/' + event.image2 + ')'}"
```